# In yasm how do I specify a 16-bit near jmp when targeting 32-bit code?

Tags: assembly, x86, yasm

I'm trying to get yasm to output a 16-bit near relative jmp. Specifically, it would be a rel16/rel32 jmp opcode with an operand size override prefix. I know `jmp short label` will emit an 8-bit near relative jmp, and a `jmp long label` will emit a 32-bit near relative jmp, but how do I get it to emit a 16-bit near relative jmp?

And specifically I'm using `bits 32` and `cpu i686`

Comment: Try `jmp near label`.

Comment: Try `jmp word label`

Comment: @fuz: that would get you a `rel16` in 16-bit mode.  In 32/64-bit modes `jmp near means `rel32`.

Answer (score 5):

**Beware that this will truncate EIP to 16-bit IP.**

The YASM/NASM syntax is `jmp word label`.  Tested with both.

YASM also incorrectly allows it in 64-bit mode<sup>1</sup>, but NASM only allows it in 32 and 16-bit modes.

---

Your choices in 32-bit code (default address/operand-size = 32) are:

- normal 2-byte `jmp/jcc rel8`.   Enforce with **`jmp short`**
- normal 5-byte `jmp rel32` or 6-byte `jcc rel32` (2-byte opcode + 4-byte rel32).  **`jmp dword`** in any mode, and `jmp near` in 32/64-bit code.
- operand-size prefix for 4-byte `jmp rel16` / 5-byte `jcc rel16` which zeros the upper 16 bits of EIP.  (Not encodeable in 64-bit mode, only 16 or 32-bit mode.)
  **`jmp word`** in 16/32-bit mode, `jmp near` in 16-bit mode.

`strict` is optional, e.g. `jmp strict short  foo`, in all of these overrides.  Even without strict, it's an error not just a warning if a rel8 can't reach for both NASM and YASM.  My examples also used `jmp`, but work with `ja`, `jle`, or any other `jcc`.  Note that [`call rel8`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/call) doesn't exist, only `rel16` and `rel32` (and indirect), using the same override syntax.

From the Operation section of [Intel's `jmp` documentation](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jmp):

```
# near jump

   ...  EIP <- EIP + DEST   for non-64-bit mode relative jumps

   IF OperandSize = 32
        THEN
             EIP ← tempEIP;                         # in 64-bit mode, this truncates RIP to EIP
        ELSE
             IF OperandSize = 16
                     THEN (* OperandSize = 16 *)
                             EIP ← tempEIP AND 0000FFFFH;     #### This line
                     ELSE (* OperandSize = 64)
                             RIP ← tempRIP;
             FI;
   FI;
```

So you can't usefully save 1 byte by adding an operand-size prefix to get a `rel16`, unless your code is executing from the low 64kiB of virtual address space.  (Or with a non-zero CS base, with IP=EIP.)

Just for fun, I verified that this is a real thing on my Skylake CPU: in a 32-bit Linux static executable, single-stepping `0x8049000 <foo>     jmpw   0x9000` in GDB gives `Cannot access memory at address 0x9000`.  Binutils `objdump` disassembles the instruction as:

```
# objdump -d -Mintel output from a 32-bit ELF executable
08049000 <foo>:
 8049000:       66 e9 fc ff             jmpw   9000 <foo-0x8040000>
```

So real execution matches this disassembly, truncating EIP to IP.

---

#### Footnote 1: In 64-bit mode: YASM and binutils bugs vs. real CPU

YASM incorrectly allows it in 64-bit mode, and GNU Binutils incorrectly decodes it as `jmp rel16` in 64-bit mode.  NASM correctly rejects `jmp word` in 64-bit mode.

But actually running it (on a Skylake) decodes it as `jmp rel32`, as documented by Intel.  (The `rel16` encoding is marked N.E. Not Encodeable in long mode).

e.g.

```
   foo: jmp word foo
   db   1, 1, 1, 1
```

assembled + linked into a Linux static executable disassembles like this with GNU Binutils 2.31.1 `objdump`:

```
0000000000401000 <foo>:
  401000:       66 e9 fc ff             jmp    1000 <foo-0x400000>
  401004:       01 01                   add    DWORD PTR [rcx],eax
  401006:       01 01                   add    DWORD PTR [rcx],eax
```

Actually running it in GDB (`starti` / `si`) shows that we fault on code-fetch from `0x1421002`, i.e. from `0x401004 + 0x0101fffc`.

That's consistent with (`66 e9 fc ff 01 01`) ignoring the meaningless operand-size prefix and decoding as a `jmp +0x0101fffc`.

Comment: Ah seems strange that you use `jmp word foo` whereas `jmp byte foo` would give an error. Regardless, good to know about the EIP truncation for rel16. My reading of that doc was that absolute targets would truncate, but not relative targets. Honestly though probably have to do some tests. Seems like with an `org 0x10000` that yasm should give an error or warning about ever using a rel16 like this

Comment: @Earlz: The block of pseudocode that applies truncation is after and separate from the `if abs else rel` block.  Just for fun, I tested to see what the tools would say (and to make double sure that my Skylake matched the documentation)